# JSP c:import parameter in code scope

Tags: java, jsp

I feel like this is a trivial question, but for some reason I can't solve it.
I want to access a c:import param as a variable in the 'code' of my JSP rather than as an EL expression

From the following JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

                <c:import url="child.jsp">
                    <c:param name="foo" value="bar"/>
                </c:import>
```

To the imported JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%

if( null == request.getAttribute("foo")  )
   throw new Exception();

%>
```

Always throws an Exception, in other words, this is not the correct way to access the parameter.

Please tell me how this should be done?

Answer (score 1):

To display the value of param try to use `request.getParameter(..)`:

```
  if( null == request.getParameter("foo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by Abdelhak is correct, but I want to add some explanations.
In your first jsp:

```
<c:import url="child.jsp">
   <c:param name="foo" value="bar"/>
</c:import>
```

is the the same as:

```
<c:import url="child.jsp?foo=bar"/>
```

**foo** is in a query string.

In your child.jsp:
You should get parameter instead of attribute since **foo** is simply not store in request scope.
Use this instead:
`request.getParameter("foo");`